# what does Error “Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)” mean?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

I got a error here when I try to build in the simulator

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
    0x101799000 <+0>: int3   
->  0x101799001 <+1>: nop
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804654/what-does-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0

Comment: You should post the Swift code that actually caused the error, not the compiled code. Also stack traces help too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that there there are instructions that lead to a crash, such as force unwrapping something that doesn't exist, and getting a value of nil.

> Take a look through your code and see if there are any situations where you force unwrap something that does not necessarily exist.