# How do I get more information about this exception?

Tags: swift, xcode, exception

I get the following error in XCode...

[image]

I've added a "Swift Error" breakpoint and left the "Type" box empty. I thought this might show some further info, but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

How can I find out where this error is arising from?

Comment: `Swift Error` breakpoints consider only **thrown** errors. Set the exception breakpoint. But I guess the function returns `nil` and the exclamation mark crashes the app. Learn how to handle optionals safely.

Comment: No, the error is coming from somewhere deep inside toJSONString. I got bored tying to step through to it.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. The exclamation mark does in fact crash the app. I wonder why its nill.

Comment: Yes, if the runtime error occurs in this line `toJSONString()` returns `nil`. Use the debugger.

Comment: The code says its not a valid JSON object for some reason. I think that situation should result in an un-handled error being propagated rather than merely returning nil.

Comment: ... that would force me to deal with the situation close to where it has arisen and give me specific information about why the undesired result has occurred.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means that you have an invalid assertion (usually a force-unwrapped nil, though a bad cast could also be the culprit, here). Make sure that tourDto is a populated var, and that it can be cast to whatever toJSONString() returns (I'm not familiar with that method, and it could also be the culprit).

Comment: Also, here, I looked up a related SO post, where someone was experiencing a similar problem, with a different method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804654/what-does-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0