# iOS App Crash due to optimisation in Xcode version above 11.3 using local var variables

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-optimization, xcode11.3, xcode11.4

I am generating a build with optimization using XCode 11.6.

The optimization build settings are

```
Apple CLang Code Generation
Optimization Level: Fastest, Smallest [-Os]
Swift Compiler - Code Generation
Optimization Level: Optimize for speed [-O]
```

I am getting a crash for the below piece of code.
Just wanted to know why I am getting a crash only for optimized build generated with XCode version above 11.3.

```
    //it crashes only when the object is declared as var not let
    var view : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.zero) 

    //lblContainer is a weak variable defined in class
    self.lblContainer = view; 
    
    //it always crashes here
    self.lblContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    self.lblContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.addSubview(self.lblContainer)
    self.lblContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
    self.lblContainer.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true;
    self.lblContainer.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true;
    self.lblContainer.leftAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8.0).isActive = true
    self.lblContainer.rightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.rightAnchor, constant: -8.0).isActive = true
```

[image: Crash Info]

You can find the [sample project](https://github.com/KirtyKumari/VarLetTest) here

Answer (score -1):

**1.** Please try to find out what is the type of  `self.lblContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled` (I'm sure that it's a Boolean) by doing `print(type(of:self.lblContainer.isUserInteractionEnabled))`

**2.** Look at this other stack overflow post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804654/what-does-error-thread-1exc-bad-instruction-code-exc-i386-invop-subcode-0x0), to find the error that appears